# Is there any way to omit a variable from super class?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

My application class uses a library that has default two variables in it.

```
   // A class from framework:

public class SuperClass implements Serializable {

  private long id;
  private long version;

  // getter and setter methods for these variables...

}
```

I should extend this class, in order to access some of the functionality of the framework.

If I extend this class to my own class like this:

```
public class MyClassChild extends SuperClass {

  private long myprimarykey;
  private String some column;
  private long myversion;

  // getter and setter methods for these variables...

}
```

As per the programming model, those two variables are also accessible.
While implementing operation that requires an Object of type `SuperClass`.

Is there any idea to extend that SuperClass which is not including those two variables `(id, version)` ?

I do not know what to do?

Any suggestions pls?

Thanks

Comment: How are those variables visible in your child class?  They are declared private, not protected.

Comment: I am guessing you are using this with an ORM framework like Hibernate or JPA?  The only way you can see those variables is via reflection.  Is it just that you don't want those variables persisted in your subclass?

Comment: Exactly man. How not to persist those two variables?

Comment: Are you using JPA Annotations?

Comment: yes, using Eclipselink [http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php].

Comment: Suggest you might want to update your question to reflect more specifically what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general JPA does not let you override superclass mappings to remove attributes, but depending on your provider it may be possible to do the following:

```
public class MyClassChild extends SuperClass {

  private long myprimarykey;
  private String some column;
  private long myversion;  

  // Override superclass mappings
  @Transient
  long getId() { return super.getId(); }
  @Transient
  void setId(long id) { return super.setId(long id); }
  // etc...
}
```

**EDIT**

In addition, it is also possible to override the values of individual columns in a mapped superclass by using the `@AttributeOverride` annotation, e.g.

```
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="EMP_ID"))
@Entity
public class MyClassChild extends SuperClass {

  private String some column;
  ...
}
```

Comment: my problem is with variable name. I do not want to have the 'Id' as Id and 'version' as version. I mean, want to have someother name.

Comment: Do you mean the column names in the table or the actual method names on your class, or both?

Comment: When I perform any operation 'select, insert or anything', those two variables 'id' & 'version' expected to be there in database table. But, If add '<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />' this in persistence.xml, those two variables are directly mapped to create the database table column. What I wanted to do is that I have use my primary key something like for ex: "EMP_ID" instead of "ID", and 'version' is not a big issue.

Comment: thanks you so much, this is what am searching for. but... Is that possible to have more than one primary key? and how the foreign key relationship can be done. I mean, do we need to specify any constraint here in the pojo class? Please, help me out in this too...

Comment: @Deab Povey:  Can you update your answer to @AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="EMP_ID")). You have missed out one comma in between. Thanks :)

Comment: Updated. Not really sure how to do the primary/foreign key relationship sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove these fields, but you can override the getters and setters to do something other than the default (this depends on their access modifiers, but they will probably be `protected` or greater).  This way you can stop the external assigning of these variables, for example.  If you choose this route, I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with the ways these fields are used in the superclass so that you can anticipate any knock-on behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  If you're inheriting, you get the entire class to come along.  If you don't want to inherit all the fields, you're not designing a subclass.

Imagine what would happen if you could omit variables - what would inherited methods do about the now-missing state?  Everything would break...

Comment: Can't be achieved this kind of operations ?

Answer (score 1):

All you can do about that is to make that variable private to the super class so subclasses do not 'see' it.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class you are supposedly adding more variables and methods, you cannot subtract.